# Can I replace source control part of TFS, but still use build automation?

Tags: svn, version-control, tfs, build-automation, tfvc

We use TFS for source control and build automation. I know that there are products that will integrate Subversion with the Visual Studio IDE, but I'm wondering is it possible to do this and continue using the build automation component of TFS or does using that require that you use TFS for the source control also?

Comment: It looks like someone has a blog post covering this: https://igorshare.wordpress.com/2010/12/26/can-tfs-be-useful-if-the-sources-are-in-subversion-svn-or-how-to-run-integration-and-nightly-builds-on-tfs-from-svn/ - I just googled for "tfs build svn" and picked the top looking link.

Comment: @DaveShaw Thanks. That looks pretty cool... probably the best solution if only I had time to implement it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS 2015 (and VSO, of course) have a build system that can integrate with any of the following options:

1. TFVC
2. TFS-hosted Git
3. External Git repository

There's no option for SVN at the moment.

Comment: Hmm... Maybe I need to explore Git more.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer no. If you want to use Team Build then you need to be using TFS for version control.

Slightly longer answer.

If you're using TFS 2013 or above you can host a [Git repository inside TFS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2013/11/13/git-for-tfs-2013.aspx). You need to create a new Team Project with Git support.

If SVN is the object of your desire then you could look at [SVN Bridge](https://svnbridge.codeplex.com/) It's not using SVN as such, it's just providing a SVN like wrapper for TFVC.

Comment: This is not strictly true.